# ROBLOX LUA(u) check arguments of a function

Tags: lua, roblox

I have this function.
As you can see, I define `fn` to run a function with arguments provided, how can I check if the amount of arguments that the `fn` function receives is the amount needed for the function `v`? Ie, if the user provides 2 args but 3 are needed, throw an error.

ModuleScript:

```lua
-- Variables
local dss = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local db = dss:GetDataStore("greenwich")

-- Tables
local greenwich = {}
local dbFunctions = {}

-- Functions
function greenwich:GetDB(name)
    local new = {}
    new.name = name
    coroutine.resume(coroutine.create(function()
        for k, v in pairs(dbFunctions) do
            local fn = function(...)
                local args = {...}
                return v(unpack(new), unpack(args))
            end
            new[k] = fn
            new[string.lower(k)] = fn
        end
    end))
    return new
end

function dbFunctions:Set(store, key, value)
    store = store.name
    db:SetAsync(store .. key, value)
    return value
end

function dbFunctions:Get(store, key)
    store = store.name
    return db:GetAsync(store .. key)
end

function dbFunctions:Delete(store, key)
    store = store.name
    local success, val = pcall(function()
        return db:RemoveAsync(store .. key)
    end)
    if val and success then
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end

function dbFunctions:Has(store, key)
    store = store.name
    return not not db:GetAsync(store .. key)
end

-- Returning everything.
return greenwich
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the standard library of Lua 5.3.5, you can use the [debug.getInfo()](https://www.lua.org/pil/23.1.html) function to inspect the function. The table that is returned contains a field called `nparams` which will tell you how many args the function expects.

```
local example = {}
function example.func(a, b, c)
    print(a, b, c)
end
local info = debug.getinfo(example.func)
print(info.nparams) -- 3
```

In Roblox Lua, which is a custom version based on Lua 5.1, the debug library is heavily modified and you'll need to use the [debug.info()](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/lua-docs/debug) function. When you pass in a function and the argument "a", it returns the arity of the function.

```
local example = {}
function example.funcA(a, b, c)
    print(a, b, c)
end
function example:funcB(a, b, c)
    print(a, b, c)
end
function example:funcC(a, b, c, ...)
    print(a, b, c)
end

-- print out the number of args and whether there's a vararg
print(debug.info(example.funcA, "a")) -- 3 false
print(debug.info(example.funcB, "a")) -- 4 false
print(debug.info(example.funcC, "a")) -- 4 true
```